# Sensor for charged particle density

Tags: planetary-science, instrument, sensors

How would I go about specifying a sensor that measures charged particles in Low Earth Orbit deployed at 1000 km?

Are there designs for instruments already that do this, or would I have to actually have someone design it for me?

It’s for a design project for school so not actually building it only designing it.

Comment: It was probably stupid to close this question which is clearly about **one problem only** with the close reason "This question needs to be more focused."  **voting to reopen ASAP!** It's a great question and I'll add a bounty to it as soon as I can. *Welcome to Stack Exchange!*